# Сохранение данных Android

Tags: криптография, android

*[Совет][Теория]*

Доброй ночи, хэшкодовцы =)
Мне стало интересно как лучше сохранять данные, которые вводит пользователь. В моем случае это пароль & логин.
Что я под этим имею:
Записывать данные в базу `SQLite` / на память телефона в файл и тому подобное.
Примером для понимания моего вопроса можно взять любое социальное приложение. Одноклассники, Вконтакте, Mail.Ru Agent, WeChat и другие.

Comment: Требуется ли как-то шифровать данные, либо вы просто ищите место, где их сохранить?

Comment: @jimpanzer я искал оптимальный способ для реализации кнопки "Запомнить меня" как на сайтах

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Теория**

В теории нельзя хранить пароли. Хранятся только пары логин и хэш пароля, лучше всего хранить хэш и отдельно от хэша [соль к паролю](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C_(%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%8F)), так чтобы:

```
хэш строка=хэш(пароль+соль) //хэш функция например MD5 или SHA1
```

Проверка пароля осуществляется в этом случае так:

1. Юзер вводит логин и пароль
2. По логину находим хэш строку (из БД)
3. По логину находим соль (в идеале в другом файле/бд)
4. Вычисляем хэш как `хэш(введенный пароль+соль)`
5. Сравниваем полученное значение с хранящимс в БД хэшем
6. В случае успеха пускаем, в случае неуспеха отражаем

**Совет**

1. Для логин/хэш создаем таблицу SQLite с индексом по логину
2. Для вычисления хэша чаще всего используется MD5 или SHA1, правда некоторые православные криптографы считают их слабыми и рекомендуют другие. Обзор криптографических хэш функций [здесь](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function)
3. Соль генерируем случайно и храним в преференсах

Comment: думаю, человек спрашивал немножко другое.

Comment: @KoVadim @Barmaley почти угадал ход моих мыслей, нужно запомнинать данные и считывать их при повторном запуске приложения... что-бы пользоватлеь по 100 раз не вводил логин/пароль.

Answer (score 3):

Для этого давным давно создан [AccountManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/accounts/AccountManager.html) и в приложениях которые вы перечислили в целом используется именно он. Как пример, могу порекомендовать [это](http://udinic.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/write-your-own-android-authenticator/)

Главное не забыть, что шифровать данные все равно нужно! :)